# Amazon RDS connection not working

Tags: iis, rds

I'm developing a Silverlight application that uses a service hosted through an ASP.NET application to communicate with my database.  The web site is not hosted on Amazon AWS, but on our own servers using IIS, we're only using Amazon RDS for the database hosting.

When I test the application locally (via visual studio) I am able to connect to the database just fine, and all calls to the database work perfectly.  Also, MySQL Workbench connects just fine.  However, when I publish the Silverlight application to my IIS server, I am unable to connect to the database at all.  I've granted access to the IP address of my server (checked this with whatismyip.com and http://checkip.amazonaws.com/) via the Amazon RDS Security Groups CIDR/IP field, but that didn't help at all.

Other posts about this problem usually involve the site being hosted on AWS or *nix, but since I'm using IIS and not hosting on AWS those solutions haven't helped any.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I downloaded MySQL Workbench on the server as well, and it has no problems connecting to the database.  The problem is only when I try to connect to the database via the Silverlight application when it's on the IIS Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!  The server needed the MySQL .NET Connector DLL's installed into the GAC.  Once that was installed, it worked perfectly.